# Get Post Analytics with Linkedin API v2

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

Recently, I am working on Linkedin API v2 and I have some problems with

- Get posts of a certain company
- Get analytics of a certain post

I was able to get company statistics by using `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization={organization URN}`

But I can't find any API to get the above info.

Please help me to resolve above problem.
Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Not yet. I didn't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Share API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api)

you can retrieve the posts of a company with the [Find Shares by Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner):

> GET
>   https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sharesPerOwner=100

```
{
    "activity": "urn:li:activity:12345657",
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [
            {
                "entity": "urn:li:article:0",
                "entityLocation": "https://www.example.com/content.html",
                "thumbnails": [
                    {
                        "imageSpecificContent": {},
                        "resolvedUrl": "https://www.example.com/image.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "description": "content description",
        "title": "Test Share with Content"
    },
    "created": {
        "actor": "urn:li:person:A8xe03Qt10",
        "time": 1471967236000
    },
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "id": "6173878065928642560",
    "lastModified": {
        "actor": "urn:li:person:A8xe03Qt10",
        "time": 1471967237000
    },
    "owner": "urn:li:organization:1000",
    "text": {
        "text": "Test Share!"
    } }
```

And about the analytics you can use the [Retrieve a Summary of Social Actions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-a-summary-of-social-actions):

> GET
>   https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/{shareUrn|ugcPostUrn|commentUrn}

```
{
    "commentsSummary": {
        "totalFirstLevelComments": 4,
        "aggregatedTotalComments": 9
    },
    "$URN": "urn:li:activity:6296748651834277888",
    "likesSummary": {
        "likedByCurrentUser": false,
        "totalLikes": 226
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your details. I also used this API but I need to get "Impressions, Reactions, Click-through rate, Comments, Shares, Clicks and Engagement rate" of a post.

Comment: I can't get the above details from the above API.

Comment: Hi @AllenHaley I retrieve this kind of info for ads with the [Ads Reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting) but I don't think they work for organic post too... you can give a try...

Answer (score 1):

Actually linkedin doesn't provide such API like facebook or twitter.
They still lack the APIs for detailed situations. You need to **scrape** data from linkedin to get further information other than those of standard linkedin API.