# Is there any APIs to get LinkedIn company posts data for the analysis?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

There are Ads, Ads Reporting, Lead Generation, Matched Audiences and Community Management.
What APIs do I have to integrate to get posts data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Linkedin doesn't support such API yet. Please check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58609023/8932715).